# category not displaying in add post ,edit post and categories page

Tags: wordpress

I have faced one problem when I have update wordpress to 3.8.1.  When I am going to add post then category list at right side panel is blank and even when I am going to edit post then also not showing.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into `screen options` in top-right corner of edit/new post page...

There will be options to hide/show parts...

Comment: I have not any option to hide/show category in `screen options`.

Comment: Try this `post_type_supports('post', 'category');`...Add this code into your theme's `functions.php` file...Hope this will work...

Comment: Or may be you can try this:-- `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'post');`

Comment: Akshay this is also not working. when I have save anything then 1-2 times categories are come and after it comes blank as like screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of days ago I had the same problem when I updated my WordPress to 3.8.1: All of my categories disappeared, but they still existed in my database.

At first I thought it was a problem with the new version, but apparently it was not as I learned through this [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/categories-and-tags-dissapeared?replies=9#post-1063716).

Apparently WordPress reacts to a full /tmp folder on your server with disappearing categories.
So I did exactly as written there, clearing my /tmp folder with following command:

```
cd /tmp
find . -exec rm {} \;
```